# Lets make a triangle

Tags: code-golf, math

Most people are familiar with Pascal's triangle.

```
    1
   1 1
  1 2 1
 1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
```

Pascal's triangle is an automaton where the value of a cell is the sum of the cells to the upper left and upper right.  Now we are going to define a similar triangle.  Instead of just taking the cells to the upper left and the upper right we are going to take all the cells along two infinite lines extending to the upper left and upper right.  Just like Pascal's triangle we start with a single `1` padded infinitely by zeros and build downwards from there.

For example to calculate the cell denoted with an `x`

```
   1
  1 1
 2 2 2
4 5 5 4
   x
```

We would sum the following cells

```
   .
  . .
 2 . 2
. 5 5 .
   x
```

Making our new cell `14`.

## Task

Given a row number (**n**), and distance from the left (**r**) calculate and output the **r**th non-zero entry from the left on the **n**th row. (the equivalent on Pascal's triangle is **nCr**).  You may assume that **r** is less than **n**.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the goal is to minimize the number of bytes in your solution.

## Test cases

```
0,0 -> 1
1,0 -> 1
2,0 -> 2
4,2 -> 14
6,3 -> 106
```

Here's the first couple rows in triangle form:

```
                  1
                1   1
              2   2   2
            4   5   5   4
          8  12  14  12   8
       16  28  37  37  28  16
     32  64  94  106 94  64  32
   64  144 232 289 289 232 144 64
 128 320 560 760 838 760 560 320 128
```

Comment: [OEIS A035002](https://oeis.org/A035002)

Comment: Can our submissions use 1-based indexing instead?

Comment: @KritixiLithos Sure.  It will make me sad though.

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
SṚ0;+Sṭ
1WWÇ⁸¡ṪṙḢ
```

Uses 0-based indexing.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/44c5ZBtbaQGotl2F4@OH2R407Di18uHPVw50zH@5Y9P/onsPL9R81rfEGYiDKAlENcxQUHjXMjfz/PzraQEfBIFaHSyHaEMYwgjFMdBSMwAwzHQXj2FgA)

#### How it works

```
1WWÇ⁸¡ṪṙḢ  Main link. Arguments: n, r

1          Set the return value to 1.
 W         Wrap; yield [1].
  W        Wrap; yield [[1]].
           This is the triangle with one row.
   Ç⁸¡     Call the helper link n times.
           Each iteration adds one row to the triangle.
      Ṫ    Tail; take the last array, i.e., the row n of the triangle.
       ṙ   Rotate row n r units to the left.
        Ḣ  Head; take the first element, i.e., entry r of row n.


SṚ0;+Sṭ    Helper link. Argument: T (triangle)

S          Take the column-wise sums, i.e., sum the ascending diagonals of the 
           centered triangle, left to right.
 Ṛ         Reverse the array of sums. The result is equal to the sums of the 
           descending diagonals of the centered triangle, also left to right.
  0;       Prepend a 0. This is required because the first element of the next row 
           doesn't have a descending diagonal.
     S     Take the column-wise sum of T.
    +      Add the ascending to the descending diagonals.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 72 bytes

1 byte thanks to Kritixi Lithos.

```python
f=lambda n,r:n>=r>=0and(0**n or sum(f(i,r)+f(i,r+i-n)for i in range(n)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VczBCoMwEATQu1@xx6xuIVXxIMR/SbFpF@ooW3vo16ehUKin4THDbO/9vqLLOYVHXC5zJIiNmIJNwUfMztc1aDV6vhaXnIpx841GT@BUCiUFWcTt6sDMeTPFXqZePHP10/mg9qBe2j8N0pWXDw)

Comment: You can rearrange to get this: `n>=r>=0and` and save a byte

Comment: @EinkornEnchanter if `n` is 0, then it gives 1; otherwise, it gives 0. It is like `n and ... or 1`, but shorter.

Comment: I see, nice abuse of broken behavior then, +1.

Comment: @EinkornEnchanter `0^0` is `1` [in most programming languages](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_zero_power).

Comment: @Arnauld That doesn't make it true ;)

Answer (score 3):

## ES6, <strike>80</strike> 78 bytes

```
p=(n,r,c=0)=>n?(o=>{while(n&&r<n)c+=p(--n,r);while(o*r)c+=p(--o,--r)})(n)||c:1
```

[In action!](https://jsfiddle.net/2ndAttmt/s6nojj9f/1/)

Two bytes thanks to Arnauld.

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by using `while(n&&r<n)` and `while(o*r)`.

Comment: This answer is perfectly valid. So, whoever downvoted it should definitely provide an explanation... Or can it be one of these weird automatic downvotes from Community?

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 94 bytes

recursive way 0-indexed

```php
function f($r,$c){for($s=$r|$c?$r<0?0:!$t=1:1;$t&&$r;)$s+=f($r-=1,$c)+f($r,$c-++$i);return$s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcxBCoAgFEXRrRQ8IrEgCRr0ExcjSU1Uvjaq1m4FTe7s3LjFspj41h3e5j34yrXgDlacLnCLpMEXrAEvgxnmGlmrWRFy04BJIEn9gV6rz8gf91JiF8RrPtgj0V1Wu4V3PXWjoPIA)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 125 bytes

0-indexed

```php
for(;$r<=$argv[1];$r++)for($z++,$c=~0;++$c<$z;$v+=$l)$x[$c]+=$t[+$r][$c]=$l=($v=&$y[$r-$c])+$x[$c]?:1;echo$t[$r-1][$argv[2]];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY1BC4JAEIXv/QwbwmUUsqBD6@IhPHSpS7dlkVhMhXCXYZHy4F@30Q4D8773wfOtn/PCt35TEzmqqPaOQtc38VRWt/vjeimF3MCTmkHpKI2S6MR3jIycX45iCZSrtdWZ4YAoFgwjYgJWTXuJCDaHUcKACt4CPhqs4TdoBDJLYKxiGNQOvhooZSLwrxXnTNa2dSxzkbG9Lh0Mr289dX2oeCsIOf8A)

### PHP>=7.1, 159 bytes

0-indexed for rows over 50

```php
for([,$m,$n]=$argv;$r<=$m;$r++)for($z++,$c=0;$c<$z;$v=bcadd($v,$l),$x[$c]=bcadd($x[$c],$l),$c++)$t[+$r][$c]=$l=bcadd(($v=&$y[$r-$c]),$x[$c])?:1;echo$t[$m][$n];
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 61 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,r:sum(f(k,r)+f(k,r+k-n)for k in range(n))or~n<-r<1
```

This returns *True* for base case **(0, 0)**, which is [allowed by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9067/12012).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY2xDoJAEERr@Irp2IXDBElMJPAlaoFyqEEWspyFjb9@giHRTDHFzJsZX@42SO59Wz3q/tzUEKPF9Oyppc4oJ19LulS4HRQd7gKt5WpJmAd9S5lqmfklk1@25yIMRr2LIysNKkSzYlC2Qzr3YmyZwzBYKP1bRIJsIVd0ckrzvxgo8@ZixVmlnA3WzaMgOihKyIn9Bw)

Comment: `~n<-r<1` is quite clever, I spent a good 10 minutes trying to golf `n>=r>=0`.

Comment: Not actually shorter, but it saves the space. :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 16 bytes

```
!!¡ȯSż+oΘ↔mΣT;;1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9odXNr//8hIcKhyK9Txbwrb86Y4oaUbc6jVDs7Mf///zP/Mg)

Same idea as Dennis' answer, but simpler indexing method.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_(programming_language)), 145 bytes

```pascal
function f(n,k:integer):integer;var i,r:integer;begin r:=1-Ord((k<0)or(k>n));if n>0 then r:=0;for i:=1 to n do r:=r+f(n-i,k-i)+f(n-i,k);f:=r;end;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5BcsMgDEXX5hTaBVLTcTvNTAaaXKFncG1wFafCQ2l6fFcQk79g0Jf0vpb@Z@iv2i/Dui4xTLH/BhxdIGcFCP9LQ8JA4CW1s0FKbnJR1Y@99RGwjY/6001IEM3pRX/EUcr5vVMhyvlMSln0QOcO0pcrI531gbd5FlIAgjFkNz5xlMZ21qjqV1nPDetozDdxpgAWtnAxUJNFiRZNYYI5QZepR6aKJk9vbdj0FzE5uYOdkcf9QeP@oEa8wauyomkK5PKAYIGwNkbWfd/LfIQyb/e1ajNWlbpcXO0r1Uax@Xle138)

Uses the `T(n, r) = T(n-1, r-1) + T(n-1, r)` recursion.